# How to draw this figure with pure tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried this figure with `tkz-euclide`.
[image]

My code

```
\documentclass[border=1.5mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{3} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{5} 
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,\a/0/B}
\tkzInterCC[R](A,\a cm)(B,\a cm) \tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzInterCC[R](C,\b cm)(B,\b cm) \tkzGetFirstPoint{X}
\tkzDefBarycentricPoint(A=1,B=1,C=1)
\tkzGetPoint{G}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center G angle 120](X) 
\tkzGetPoint{Y}
\tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center G angle 240](X) 
\tkzGetPoint{Z}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,X,Y,Z)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](B,X)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](Y)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](Z)
\tkzLabelSegments[sloped](A,Z A,Y C,X B,X C,Y B,Z){\SI{\b}{cm}}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,Z B,Z B,X C,X C,Y A,Y)
\tkzLabelSegments[sloped](C,B){\SI{\a}{cm}}
\tkzLabelSegments[sloped, above](A,C){\SI{\a}{cm}}
\tkzLabelSegments(A,B){\SI{\a}{cm}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to redraw the figure without loading `tkz-euclide` but only `tikz`?

Comment: Yes. You are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```tex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1.5mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  % the first two styles are borrowed from my own article (in Chinese)
  % https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/82427838
  dot/.style={
    circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt
  },
  dot label/.style={
    circle, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=1pt
  },
  midway label/.style={
    midway, sloped, below
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path
    (0,0) coordinate (A)
    (3,0) coordinate (B)
    (60:3) coordinate (C)
    (1.5,{.5*sqrt(3)}) coordinate (O); % center of the whole figure

  % Get coordinate X
  \path[name path=circle B] (B) circle[radius=5cm];
  \path[name path=circle C] (C) circle[radius=5cm];
  \pgfresetboundingbox % trick!
  \draw[name intersections={of=circle B and circle C}]
    (intersection-1) coordinate (X);
  
  % Get coordinates Y and Z
  \draw ([rotate around={120:(O)}]X) coordinate (Y);
  \draw ([rotate around={-120:(O)}]X) coordinate (Z);
  
  % draw segments and put midway labels
  \draw (A) -- (Z) node[midway label] {5cm}
            -- (B) node[midway label] {5cm}
            -- (A) node[midway label] {3cm};
  \draw (B) -- (X) node[midway label] {5cm}
            -- (C) node[midway label] {5cm}
            -- (B) node[midway label] {3cm};
  \draw (C) -- (Y) node[midway label] {5cm}
            -- (A) node[midway label] {5cm}
            -- (C) node[midway label, above] {3cm};

  % label coordinates
  \foreach \i/\angle in {A/180, B/0, C/90, X/0, Y/180, Z/-90} {
    \node[dot, label={[dot label]\angle:$\i$}] at (\i) {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps not the simplest... I've lost familiarity with `tikz` tricks/conventions for some time.

**Update**

- Input is "parameterized" to only depend on `\shortside` and `\longside`, with the center of figure shifted to (0, 0).
- A general way of how to measure and store lengths of segments in macros, then convert them to target unit with desired number of places is shown, though not necessary for current figure.
  This is kind of reinventing `tkz-euclide`.

```tex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1.5mm, 12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% usage: \measureSegmentInIntegralCm{A}{B}{\lengthAB}
\newcommand\measureSegmentInIntegralCm[3]{
  \path let \p1 = ($ (#1) - (#2) $),
            \n1 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
        in \pgfextra
           \pgfmathsetmacro#3{\n1}\global\let#3=#3
           \endpgfextra;
  % now #3 is in pt. Convert it to cm and round to integer.
  \edef#3{\qty{\fpeval{round(\UseName{dim_to_decimal_in_cm:n}{#3 pt})}}{cm}}
}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  % the first two styles are borrowed from my own article (in Chinese)
  % https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/82427838
  dot/.style={
    circle, fill=black, inner sep=1pt, outer sep=0pt
  },
  dot label/.style={
    circle, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=1pt
  },
  midway label/.style={
    midway, sloped, below
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \newcommand\shortside{3}
  \newcommand\longside{5}

  % specify coordinates O, A, B, and C
  \path
    (0,0) coordinate (O) % center
    (-150:{\shortside * sqrt(3)/3}) coordinate (A)
    ([rotate around={120:(O)}]A) coordinate (B)
    ([rotate around={240:(O)}]A) coordinate (C);

  % specify coordinate X
  \path[name path=circle B] (B) circle[radius=\longside cm];
  \path[name path=circle C] (C) circle[radius=\longside cm];
  \pgfresetboundingbox % trick!
  \draw[name intersections={of=circle B and circle C}]
    (intersection-1) coordinate (X);

  % specify coordinates Y and Z
  \path
    ([rotate around={120:(O)}]X) coordinate (Y)
    ([rotate around={240:(O)}]X) coordinate (Z);

  % compute distances AB and BX in integral cm
  \measureSegmentInIntegralCm{A}{B}{\a}
  \measureSegmentInIntegralCm{B}{X}{\b}
  
  % quick way
  % \edef\a{\qty{\shortside}{cm}}
  % \edef\b{\qty{\longside}{cm}}

  % draw segments and put midway labels
  \draw (A) -- (Z) node[midway label] {\b}
            -- (B) node[midway label] {\b}
            -- (A) node[midway label] {\a};
  \draw (B) -- (X) node[midway label] {\b}
            -- (C) node[midway label] {\b}
            -- (B) node[midway label] {\a};
  \draw (C) -- (Y) node[midway label] {\b}
            -- (A) node[midway label] {\b}
            -- (C) node[midway label, above] {\a};

  % label coordinates
  \foreach \i/\angle in {A/180, B/0, C/90, X/0, Y/180, Z/-90} {
    \node[dot, label={[dot label]\angle:$\i$}] at (\i) {};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I avoid typing 5cm and 3 cm when I change AB and BC? In mycode, I used `\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{3} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\b}{5}`

Comment: You can still use that way. I just added an updated example showing different possibilities.

Answer (score 8):

<s>While you are waiting for Tikz-help</s> Purely for comparison, here is a [lualatex](https://www.luatex.org/) version, drawn with the built-in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) language.

[image]

You need to compile this one with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
numeric a, b, r, s; 
a = 3cm; b = 5cm;
r = a +-+ 1/2 a;
s = b +-+ 1/2 a;

pair A, B, C, X, Y, Z;
A = up scaled 2/3 r rotated 120;
B = A rotated 120; C = B rotated 120;

X = up scaled (1/3 r + s) rotated 300;
Y = X rotated 120; Z = Y rotated 120;

draw A -- B -- C -- cycle;
draw A -- Z -- B -- X -- C -- Y -- cycle;

dotlabel.llft("$A$", A);
dotlabel.lrt ("$B$", B);
dotlabel.top ("$C$", C);

dotlabel.urt ("$X$", X);
dotlabel.ulft("$Y$", Y);
dotlabel.bot ("$Z$", Z);

def show_size_in_cm(expr a, b) = 
  save d; numeric d; d = round(abs(a-b) / cm);
  save t; picture t; t = thelabel.top("\textsf{\scriptsize " & decimal d & "\thinspace cm}", origin);
  draw t rotated angle (b-a) shifted 1/2[a,b];
enddef;

show_size_in_cm(A, B);
show_size_in_cm(A, C);
show_size_in_cm(C, B);
show_size_in_cm(C, X);
show_size_in_cm(B, X);
show_size_in_cm(Y, A);
show_size_in_cm(Y, C);
show_size_in_cm(A, Z);
show_size_in_cm(Z, B);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A more compact but not better

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) coordinate(A) -- (3cm,0) coordinate(B);
\path (A) -- ++(60:3cm)coordinate(C);
\draw (A)node[left]{A} --node[midway, sloped,below]{3cm} (B)node[right]{B} -- node[midway, sloped,below]{3cm}(C)node[above]{C} 
--node[midway, sloped,below]{3cm}cycle;

\path[name path=CA] (A) circle (5cm);
\path[name path=CB] (B) circle (5cm);
\path[name path=CC] (C) circle (5cm);

\path[name intersections={of=CB and CA}] coordinate (Z) at (intersection-2);
\path[name intersections={of=CB and CC}]  coordinate (X) at (intersection-1);
\path[name intersections={of=CC and CA}]  coordinate (Y) at (intersection-1);

\draw (A) --node[midway, sloped,below]{5cm}
     (Z)node[below]{Z} 
     -- node[midway, sloped,below]{5cm}(B)
     --node[midway, sloped,below]{5cm}
     (X)node[right]{X}
     --node[midway, sloped,below]{5cm}(C)
     --node[midway, sloped,below]{5cm}
     (Y)node[left]{Y}
     --node[midway, sloped,below]{5cm}cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A direct math solution by calculating the height of the isosceles triangles.
(Using the angle leads to some noticable imprecisions.)

I chose to place the annotations along the lines consistently on the outside of the figure. Even though `auto` is set which would solve this, the `sloped` options disturbs this placement again.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={a=3; b=5;},
  a node/.style={edge node={node[sloped,#1]{3\,cm}}},
  b node/.style={edge node={node[sloped,#1]{5\,cm}}},
  dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=+0pt,
    minimum size=+.4em, outer sep=+0pt, label position=center},
  node quotes mean={
    label={[dot, label={[direction shorthands,#2]{$#1$}}]center:}},
  outer/.style args={#1:#2}{
    edge node={coordinate[sloped, allow upside down, shift=(down:\height),#2](#1)}},
  auto]
\pgfmathsetmacro\height{sqrt(b*b-a*a/4)}
\draw (0,0) coordinate["A" left ] (A) to[outer=Z:"Z" below, a node=']  +(0:a)
            coordinate["B" right] (B) to[outer=X:"X" right, a node  ] +(60:a)
            coordinate["C"      ] (C) to[outer=Y:"Y" left , a node  ] cycle
                (A) to[b node='] (Z)
   to[b node='] (B) to[b node='] (X)
   to[b node  ] (C) to[b node  ] (Y)
   to[b node='] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]